# layer_styles table not available in QGIS 3.16, works in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, style

Layer styles stored in a postgres database (postgres server version 9.5.22) are not available in QGIS 3.16 (Message from Database Styles Manager: No styles found in the database).
Everything works fine in my QGIS 3.10 Version. Are there other settings I need to take care of, or could it be the version difference in the PostgreSQL client of 12.3 for QGIS 3.16 and 11.3 for QGIS 3.10?

Here is a screenshot of the version info for QGIS 3.16:
[image: QGIS 3.16 Version info]

Here is the screenshot of the version info for QGIS 3.10:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem after upgrading from QGIS 3.10 to 3.16.3

When clicking on "Style > Load Styles > From database (postgres)" for a vector layer none of the existing styles appeared, only showing "no styles found in database"

[image]

Checking the Postgresql log file showed QGIS 3.16 was looking for a column called 'type' that contains a string such as 'Polygon' but can also be empty. Log lines below:

> 2021-02-08 11:25:30.566 UTC [14640] user_name@database_name ERROR:
> column "type" does not exist at character 191
>
> 2021-02-08 11:25:30.566 UTC [14640] user_name@database_name STATEMENT:
> SELECT id,styleName,description FROM layer_styles WHERE
> f_table_catalog='database_name' AND f_table_schema='schema_name' AND
> f_table_name='table_name' AND f_geometry_column='geom' AND
> (type='Polygon' OR type IS NULL) ORDER BY useasdefault DESC,
> update_time DESC

The workaround that resolved this was to add column 'type' to the layer_styles table, by running this psql command.

```
ALTER TABLE layer_styles ADD COLUMN type VARCHAR DEFAULT null;
```

You might be able to alter the layer_styles table directly through QGIS instead of using psql. Just make sure your postgresql connection has 'Also list tables with no geometry', and your login credentials allow editing of the layer_styles table structure.

After adding the 'type' column I tested editing an existing style in 3.16 and sure enough it populated the 'type' column with the string 'Polygon'.